# What does the tag politics stand for?

Tags: support

Politics can be defined from concerning potentially everything (as done by Carl Schmidt) and something that one cannot connect at all with a Q&A on the english language. Thus, there's need for a documenation of the "politics" tag.

Concretely, I was wondering if I could tag [Is there any initiative or movement trying to abolish capitalization of I, nations and religions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334680/is-there-any-initiative-or-movement-trying-to-abolish-capitalization-of-i-natio) with "politics".

Comment: Any user with more than 300 reputation points can create whatever tag they want. When the site started, it was just one reputation point required to create a tag. This is the first time I saw the tag and I don't understand what that tag is for. One of the question seems to be related with "political correctness" instead of "politics". Not many users of ELU care so much about tags. Whatever tag you use for your question, your question's received four close-votes and I believe it will be closed as it has nothing to do with English Language and Usage.

Comment: If you click on the [tag:politics] link, you'll see the 34 current questions. Among possible other things, what they have in common is 'something to do with politics'. Does your question have that same vague connection? Personally, either way would sound OK to me. Having the tag isn't obviously wrong, it could easily be associated with some kind of political movement. Not having the tag isn't obviously wrong because only the most extreme intellectual political movement would care about spelling reform of such narrow demands.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that [politics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) currently has no tag wiki.
How it should be used is therefore undefined and open to interpretation.

You, and anyone else, are entitled to propose a tag wiki definition.  It is then reviewed just like any suggested edit - with the proviso that the reviewers must have 5,000 reputation rather than the 2,000 for regular edit suggestions.

Having tags without guidance is something of a vacuum in any site.  You would be doing the site a favour by filling it in with a good concise definition.

Comment: Can I ask you why you voted to reopen this question? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355442/equivalent-for-crowd-in-the-context-of-machines